# Вопрос про использование static переменных на Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Можно ли использовать public static переменные чисто для удобства, менять их из других скриптов, чем это грозит? Банальные примеры: количество жизней, проверка bool, скорость и т.п. Хочу разобраться пока не поздно, чтоб в будущем не переделывать.

Comment: не знаю, как в юнити, но в энтерпрайзе статические переменные не рекомендую использовать. Они способствуют связыванию кода в лапшу и уменьшают возможности тестирования кода. К тому же очень легко поддаться соблазну плодить статические переменные везде по проекту и получить в итоге не просто нетестируемую мешанину, но и периодически  падающую на многопоточных сценариях с непонятными причинами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В таком контексте использование статических переменных, несомненно, является очень плохой практикой и приводит к очень сильной связанности кода.

Касаемо того, можно ли использовать статические переменные в Unity в целом, ответ - да. В качестве примера (не самого хорошего семантически), можно рассмотреть реализацию анти-паттерна [Singleton с wiki Unity3d](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton).  В данном примере синглтон реализован по средствам статических полей.

```
public class Singleton<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static bool m_ShuttingDown = false;
    private static object m_Lock = new object();
    private static T m_Instance;

    public static T Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_ShuttingDown)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("[Singleton] Instance '" + typeof(T) +
                "' already destroyed. Returning null.");
                return null;
             }

        lock (m_Lock)
        {
            if (m_Instance == null)
            {
                // Search for existing instance.
                m_Instance = (T)FindObjectOfType(typeof(T));

                // Create new instance if one doesn't already exist.
                if (m_Instance == null)
                {
                    // Need to create a new GameObject to attach the singleton to.
                    var singletonObject = new GameObject();
                    m_Instance = singletonObject.AddComponent<T>();
                    singletonObject.name = typeof(T).ToString() + " (Singleton)";

                    // Make instance persistent.
                    DontDestroyOnLoad(singletonObject);
                }
            }

            return m_Instance;
        }
    }
}
```

В этом конкретном примере, статически гарантируется наличие определенного GameObject. В какой-либо произвольной реализации статических полей возможен случай, когда вы будете иметь возможность обратиться к статической переменной класса унаследованного от MonoBehaviour, который еще не создан на момент обращения. Что касается обычных (не-MonoBehaviour) классов, тут опасностей такого роде легче избежать.

Comment: странная реализация - всегда использует блокировку. Это [напоминает блокировку с двойной проверкой](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/Singleton), только с одной проверкой :)

Comment: @tym32167, согласен и может не считаться эталоном. Решил привести в ответ реализацию (чужую, не свою) только в плане примера применения статических переменных